# How to include SSIS variable to a header row in flat file destination

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I would like to use SSIS variable as a part of my header row in flat file destination. Is there a way to do that?

[image: See the picture here]

Comment: if your source is SQL query, i would easily use Union query for header /footer row

Answer (score 1):

Use a script component in the control flow to add the header to the empty file and then have your data flow ignore headers.